# Where to perform view controller "business logic"?

Tags: ios, oop, swift, architecture, ios8

I was working in a view controller and when I completed it, I had the following in the onViewDidLoad  (I simplified the code/variables but the idea is the same):

```
    //Show Fields
    txtField1.hidden = _settings.showField1 == true
    txtField2.hidden = _settings.userNeedsField2 == true

    //Display some other text about weather
    if (_myWeatherService.TheMoonIsFull && _settings.userNeedsField3)
    {
        lblField3.text = "Some text about something"
    }
    else {
        txtField3.hidden = true
    }

    //Handle Time Stuff
    if (_settings.UserPreferenceTimeOfDay == true) {
       if ((current24ClockHourInTheDay >= 5 && current24ClockHourInTheDay <= 18))
          {
            txtField4.hidden = true
            txtField5.text = "DAY"
          }
       else {
            txtField4.hidden = true
            txtField5.text = "NIGHT"
        }
    else {
            txtField4.hidden = false
            txtField5.text = ""
        }
```

And this continues on for another 20 or so lines.

Basically I feel like there is a mixture of stuff probably best to leave in a view controller (presentation-related decisions) but some of it I reuse in other view controllers. Also some of the logic like based on the user's preference for time of day and hours of the day confuses me about where it should be (should some service handle these decisions instead, so I can reuse this code)?

Thanks!

Comment: I would suggest to look at [MVP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93presenter) and/or [VIPER](https://www.objc.io/issues/13-architecture/viper/) architectural patterns.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you already have something in place as your `_settings` object. Consider creating convenience methods in `_settings` that encapsulate the conditions you wish to use to modify your UI. For example, instead of just having an accessor for `UserPreferenceTimeOfDay`, wrap up a selector for `timeOfDayString`.

```
txtField5.text = _settings.timeOfDayString;
txtField4.hidden = ([txtField5.text length] == 0);

- (NSString *)timeOfDayString {
  if (self.UserPreferenceTimeOfDay) {
    if (self.current24ClockHourInTheDay >= 5 && current24ClockHourInTheDay <= 18) {
      return @"DAY";
    } else {
      return @"NIGHT";
    }
  }
  return @"";
}
```

**Note**: I just realized that you're using swift, but I'm no master of swift programming. The theory should be the same, though.

Answer (score 0):

I can't get the main idea of this code, but if you want to reuse some code, you have to take it to a separate view controller and when you need this functionality, you just instantiate the controller and use it ... In your case all user time preferences can be separated in a UserTimePreferencess.swift file (view controller). If you don't want to have so much code in viewDidLoad, you can move this code in functions elsewhere in the view controller and just call them in viewDIdLoad